# I have vs-code installed on a Mac and since a few hours it won't underline errors in Rust

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code

Yeah due to Christmas I went over to my mother but still wanted to improve my skills in rust.
 For one day everything just worked fine, but now vscode doesn't underline the errors. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM5ui.jpg

here a pic how it looks, I have rust-analyzer installed. 
It should underline something because the method doesn't return. anything.

Do you have any idea how to get rid of the Issue I already reinstalled twice.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in main.rs?

If you are in a module file or lib.rs you need to import the files with `use`.

Other than that, I don't know, you could try enabling

```
    "rust-analyzer.trace.extension": true,
```

In your settings.json file and checking your log output.

I had some issues after installing the latest version so you may want to head to the rust-analyzer extension page, click the drop-down arrow next to `Uninstall` and selecting `Install older version`, I just used a version that was 11 days old and it seemed to fix things.

EDIT: [There is an issue showing VSCode downloads the wrong/old version.](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/11098)

Comment: thanks but nothing worked

Comment: update:  it works now but I don't know why

Comment: i don't have changed anything

Comment: anyways fine for me

Comment: mark my answer thanks ;) I need reputation